# VBA to attach Excel file without saving

Tags: excel, vba

I have created Excel file and want to attach the same in outlook email without saving excel file. I am able to attach the file once it is saved in folder and but I don't want to save it anywhere. Please assist.

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wkb1 As Worksheet

Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
Set wkb1 = Worksheets(1)
wkb1.Name = "Training Tracker"

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Sheet5.Range("B2").Value
         wkb.Activate
        .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook)
        .Display
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a saved copy somewhere to send it. What you can do is save a copy of it to your temp folder. This folder is cleared down by the OS regularly and won't intervene with the users folder (works on windows not mac)

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wkb1 As Worksheet

Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
Set wkb1 = Worksheets(1)
wkb1.Name = "Training Tracker"

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = Sheet5.Range("B2").Value
     wkb.Activate
     wkb.SaveCopyAs Environ("temp") & "\TempFileName.xls"
    .Attachments.Add (Environ("temp") & "\TempFileName.xls")
    .Display
End With
```